# How to show associated headers next to children values?

Tags: python

Please some help, I'm new with python and I don't know how to begin with this.

I have a column like this, whith blocks of info separated with "headers" beggining with 'AW':

```
AW ABC  
x       
y       
z       
AW DEF  
w       
p       
o       
y       
t       
AW QQWL
h       
k
```

How can I print to the rigth the header related with corresponding values like this?

```
AW ABC      
x       AW ABC
y       AW ABC
z       AW ABC
AW DEF  
w       AW DEF
p       AW DEF
o       AW DEF
y       AW DEF
t       AW DEF
AW QQWL
h       AW QQWL
k       AW QQWL
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

*UPDATE*

My current code I was able to do is like this:

```
column='''AW ABC
x
y
z
AW DEF
w
p
o
y
t
AW QQWL
h
k'''

values = column.split("\n")

for v in values:
   if "AW" in v:
      s = v
      print v
   else:
      print s, v
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: post your code .

Comment: If you new to Python but e.g. know JavaScript, a natural approach is to first solve it in JavaScript and then figure out what your solution would look like when translated. The resulting code won't be idiomatic Python, but this approach would get you past the point of not knowing where to start. Also, the question is unclear. What do you mean by "I have a column". Is this a list of strings? One big string? A pandas dataframe? A text file? You haven't provided enough details to make your scenario reproducible by others.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  We generally expect you to post your coding attempt.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added my attempt below update on original post.

Comment: @Prune Added update

Comment: @JohnColeman Added update

Comment: Your existing code is the most straightforward way to handle this.  You can use a conditional expression to stuff all of that into one line of code, but it will be harder to read and modify.

Comment: @Prune I understand. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

```
column='''AW ABC
x
y
z
AW DEF
w
p
o
y
t
AW QQWL
h
k'''

for line in column.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('AW'):
        head = line
    else:
        line = f'{line}{head:>12}'
    print(line)
```

The output:

```
AW ABC
x      AW ABC
y      AW ABC
z      AW ABC
AW DEF
w      AW DEF
p      AW DEF
o      AW DEF
y      AW DEF
t      AW DEF
AW QQWL
h     AW QQWL
k     AW QQWL
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What does mean the whole and each part of this expresson `f'{line}{head:>12}`?

Comment: @GerCas, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals